# Composer-setup : Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

We are getting following error while installing `composer-setup.exe`:

```
Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org

Proxy http://proxy.mycompany.com:1234 [from Internet Settings] failed with errors:
Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authorization Required

Request to http://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
Failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

My Project Environment details are

- Windows 7
- Apache v2.2.22
- PHP v5.4.3

`php.ini`:

- php_curl enabled
- php_openssl enabled

Please help us to installing `Composer-Setup.exe` for Laravel Framework.

Comment: Should be "https" not "http"

Comment: And the second error says "Proxy Authorization Required" - so seems like a local issue to setup your configuration to your proxy correctly.

Answer (score 2):

## Env

xampp
php 5.6.3
windows 7 64bit

## Solution

1. save [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) to your local path(eg.d:/download/ca-bundle.crt);
2. double click `ca-bundler.crt` to import it;
3. add the two line to php.ini

   > curl.cainfo=d:/download/ca-bundle.crt
   >   openssl.cafile=d:/download/ca-bundle.crt
4. try to install `Composer-Setup.exe` again.

refer to:[https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798#issuecomment-133869395)